# sudo crash on start up error message

Tags: dpkg

https://gyazo.com/0b72be67d7338c58b5bcf9de8d5aa26b
Above is a screenshot of the error.

Haven't touched the computer in a week, and it was turned off all the time.
Should I mind the message or just leave it be?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure because the important part of that debug dump (the stack trace) is missing. It could be because the package manager (dpkg) cannot find the USB drive or CD you used to install Ubuntu.